# Regex for nested variables

Tags: regex

I am parsing JSON files for localisation and try to lock variables from extraction, however I run into problem with nested variants of variables.

I have tried (and failed) to find a regular expression to capture the variables. The sought for behaviour is:

- Capture content within {curly brackets}
- Except when above content appears within curly brackets
- In these cases instead capture content from first '{' to subsequent '{', and from each following '}' to '{'

Below snippet is marked up with the translatable text in bold, and it's the other content I'm trying to capture to lock it:

---

"{numberOfMachines} **machines selected**"

"**Failed to send** {commandName, select, PARK {**park**} START {**start**}} **command**"

---

An alternative workaround would be to only capture "single" variables (from line 1) and leave the nested variants (line 2) untouched to be handled manually. For this I tried the following expression: `{\w+(?![{}]\S)}` but this also captures the `{park}`.

Any help to find the correct expression is much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: PS. Please note that the software I'm using is restricted to only use regex, so any comment that I shouldn't use regex for this is not very valuable :)

Comment: You might want to consider using a parser here.